# How to get rid of dots from a float value without changing the value - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, floating-point, dot

So I have an ID column in my df that is something like this:

```
ID
93.18767
93.87657
94.87246
95.87323
```

I have to get rid of the dot keeping all the numbers as they are, like this:

```
ID
9318767
9387657
9487246
9587323
```

I tried using replace, but when I transform this column to string I get some strange values. Here is the method I normally use:

```
def substitute (df,column,before,after):
    df[column]=df[column].astype(str)
    df[column]=df[column].str.replace(before,after)
    return 'Done'
```

But I get something like this when I use that method:

```
 ID
931876599999994
938764388899999994
948724388555599999
9587322999994300000002
```

I know that this happens when I try to convert the column to string and that is because of how floats are stored, but I couldnt find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Solution:
I needed to determine the number of decimal numbers in my column, and then use the replace

```
df[ID] = df[ID].apply(lambda x: '{0:.4f}'.format(x))
substitute (df,'ID',before,after)
```

Comment: you probably didn't escape teh `.` which is a special character in regex `df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace('\.','')`

Comment: Look like changing input `93.18767` to a number is where the problem occurred.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Can you post the whole code, including how you create the dataframe, call `substitute` and print the result ?

Comment: @Chris I dont think so, since some the number is changing not only getting more decimal characters

Comment: @Umar.H I get the same problem using regex =/

Comment: @joao I get the dataframe by reading a database with pd.read_csv and it is very very large. The problem happens when  df[column]=df[column].astype(str) is called, but I can't think of a way to remove the dot without converting to string...

Comment: @Suetam016, your dataFrame column is `float64`? if yes then it should work, see if the given solution works for you.

Comment: @KarnKumar yes the column is float64

Comment: This is really strange as i have reproduced the same `float` values and working perfectly fine!

Comment: @KarnKumar the pointed solution worked. Thank you. I used df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: '{0:.4f}'.format(x)) to limit the number of decimal numbers then used a simple replace. Thank you everyone! Will eddit my question with the solution now.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got the solution, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string, remove dot and to int again:

```
s = pd.Series([93.18767, 93.87657, 94.87246, 95.87323], name='ID')
s.astype(str).str.replace('.', '').astype(int)
```

output:

```
0    9318767
1    9387657
2    9487246
3    9587323
```

Alternatively, if your data is always in the form xx.xxxxx, you can multiply by the necessary power of ten to reach integer (here 1e5):

```
(s*1e5).astype(int)
```

Comment: Bro the alternative is not perfect but I can make it work, very smart thank you. 
The replace still didint work unfortunately

Comment: The only thing is, I am getting rounded values, some 93.18767 are becoming 9318768 and some are staying 9318767... that will cause some problems in my analisys, but it is the closest I've got so far   ):)

Comment: I find it weird that the conversion to string fails. Can you provide the full dataset of your column?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can try below with   [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) + [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

### DataFrame Sample:

```
>>> df
         ID
0  93.18767
1  93.87657
2  94.87246
3  95.87323
```

**Method One**: if your intention to simply remove `.` from the `float` value and not to get them as `float` after removing dot then use below.

```
>>> df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace(".", "")
0    9318767
1    9387657
2    9487246
3    9587323
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

**Second**, way around to remove `dots` from numbers and then again convert that to the type `int` ie literally `int64`.

```
>>> df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace(".", "").astype("int")
0    9318767
1    9387657
2    9487246
3    9587323
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

**Another**, way around to remove `dots` from numbers and then again convert that to the type `float` ie literally `float64` but you will get at the end of the numbers though.

```
>>> df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace(".", "").astype("float64")
0    9318767.0
1    9387657.0
2    9487246.0
3    9587323.0
Name: ID, dtype: float64
```

**Another Trick:**
since \D matches any [non-decimal digit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
>>> df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+', '')
0    9318767
1    9387657
2    9487246
3    9587323
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: With method one I get: numbers like 9301645909999999 :(
With the second one i get an overflow error, changing the int to double I get: 9.301645e+15
With the third method I get the same thing as the second
With the last trick I still get: 9301644959999999 :(

Thank you for the answer, but I believe this thing happens when converting to string. Since this ID refers to contract_number.client_number I need the converted string to be exactly the same as the float number =/

Comment: This is really strange, i have also `float64` as dtype for `ID` column and all these working, Which version of pandas you have?